# How can I read all Active Directory computers into an array in PowerShell?

Tags: file, loops, powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

When I do:

```
# Gets all domain-joined computer names and properties in one object
$strCategory = "computer"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.Filter = ("(objectCategory=$strCategory)")

$colProplist = "name"

foreach ($i in $colPropList) {
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
}

$Reader = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($Computer in $Reader) {
   Write-Host $Computer
}
```

`$Computer` comes out as `System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult`. How can I query Active Directory for all computers and store their string values into an array like this?

I need to keep the `foreach` syntax (i.e. `foreach $Computer in $Reader`) because my code is such that `$Reader` can also accept a file of computers like so:

```
$Reader = Get-Content ((Resolve-Path $iL).Path)
```

In summary, I want something that works with both an input file OR by querying AD using the same looping syntax.

**EDIT**: My input file is a text file that separates computer names by a newline as in the following:

```
win7box1
win7box2
win10box3
```

Comment: Why not use `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties *` for instance ?

Comment: I want something that works with both an input file OR by querying AD using the same looping syntax. I'm not sure how what you're describing would work.

Comment: [Parameter Sets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets/)?

Comment: Please show us what your input file looks like

Comment: Get-ADComputer all the way...!

Comment: And also, except writing its name to the host, what do you plan to do with each computer name?

Comment: @sodawillow I have updated with the information you requested. I am running WMI commands on each -- but that part is taken care of. I just need to extract a string of computer names in one looping construct, whether from an input file or querying AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. To get a string from `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`, you could just do a loop as in my example, and do:

```
foreach ($Computer in $Reader) {
     $ComputerString = $Computer.Properties.Name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Reader = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samAccountName

foreach ($Computer in $Reader) {
   #WMI processing
}
```

Should do the trick. No need for more.

You could use `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` for performance reasons, though. **Or** use a real filter, not `*`.

I guess you took your code from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/585223/how-to-list-all-computers-operating-system-on-a-network-in-powershell), if you have not tried anything else before, it is not the easiest choice PowerShell offers.

**Edit:**

You need the ActiveDirectory module loaded for `Get-ADComputer` to be available (`Import-Module ActiveDirectory`).

... and you need [RSAT](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsat) installed for the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module to be available.

**Edit 2:**

Well without RSAT installed, obviously, this answer becomes pointless.

Comment: Is there a reason I would be getting `The term 'Get-ADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program.`?

Comment: I cant guarantee that module will be installed on the peoples' computers who run this. Is there another way?

Comment: Sad. Updating again, I cannot run tests with `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` right now but I'm sure someone around knows how to get an array of hostnames out of it : ).